# How to remove "replacement character" "�" from column in Vertica

Tags: regex, database, vertica

I have a column in my HP vertica database which has a replacement character in middle (I do not know where it came from).

I want to replace all replacement characters asap with character 'n'. Is there any method to do it? I have search a lot, I am still unsuccessful. I know the problem is related to Unicode.

Any way via which I can remove all replacement character?

**Sample**: Pi�on CCD Navajo County Arizona

PS: I do not have time to import the files again.

Comment: you sure the char's really bad in the db, and not simply being corrupted upon retrieval?

Comment: Yes. Its not on all the rows.

Comment: If it is, then you may try matching it with `\uFFFD` code.

Comment: is the only out of place character � or are there others? are you trying to go through and change the DB directly or are you trying to adjust the DB output?

Comment: The `�` glyph can be any character that the current font has no glyph for. In this case its U+FFFD. Are you sure it's the same codepoint that you are looking at?

Comment: reload the data , it will be much faster !

Comment: Do a replace on load. An update is a lot more costly.